# Why doesn't AngularJS controller scope work like regular javascript scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In [vanilla javascript](http://vanilla-js.com/) I can do:

```
run();
function run() {};
```

In angular though it seems I have to predefine all the functions on a scope before I can run them:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fxn = function() {
    $scope.status = 'working';
  };
  $scope.fxn();
});
```

Because this throws the error `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'fxn'`:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.fxn();
  $scope.fxn = function() {
    $scope.status = 'working';
  };
});
```

Am I missing something? Is angular enforcing a best-practice?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Angular. Just javascript. You are trying to call a object method before you define it. Of course it will fail. Object methods *don't hoist*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$scope is an object in angular.

In vanilla js, you cannot do:

```
var x = {};
x.alert("hi");
x.alert = function(msg) { alert(msg); }
```

When you do

```
run();
function run() {};
```

You have function hoisting going on, which is where all function definitions get "hoisted" to the top, so it works as if you had

```
function run() {};
run();
```

If you had done, on the other hand:

```
run(); //TypeError: undefined is not a function
otherrun(); //ReferenceError: otherrun is not defined
var run = function() {}
```

The difference, is again hoisting, this time it is variable hoisting.  That code is the equivalent of:

```
var run;
run(); //TypeError: undefined is not a function
otherrun(); //ReferenceError: otherrun is not defined
run = function() {}
```

Where the declaration (but not assignment) of a variable is hoisted to the top.

It's all pretty confusing at first, but if you google javascript hoisting and read a few articles, you should get a good feel for how it works.

Comment: Thanks @dave, I am aware of hoisting but not of the nuances you showed. I assumed that `function run(){}` was the same as `var run = function(){}` and that declaring a global function was the same as assigning it to the window which is done implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is between function statements and function expressions. Function statements act as if they are lifted to the top of the current scope. Function expressions aren't. So

```
run();
function run() {}
```

is equivalent to

```
function run() {};
run();
```

However,

```
run();
var run = function () {};
```

is **not** equivalent to

```
var run = function () {};
run();
```

Rather, it's equivalent to

```
var run;
run();
run = function () {};
```

which will fail to run.